# IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 2

Tags: python, pytorch

here is the dataset:

```
class price_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, transform=None):
        xy = pd.read_csv('data_balanced_full.csv')

        self.n_samples = xy.shape[0]

        xy = xy.to_numpy()
        self.x_data = torch.from_numpy(xy[:, 7:].astype(np.float32))
        self.y_data = torch.from_numpy(xy[:, 6].astype(np.float32))
        self.transform = transform

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.x_data[index]
        y = self.y_data[index]

        sample = {'data': x, 'label': y}
        if self.transform:
            sample = self.transform(sample)

        return sample

    # we can call len(dataset) to return the size
    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_samples
```

and I'm trying to split the dataset into testing and training:

```
dataset_normalized = price_dataset(transform=transforms.ToTensor())
train_dataset, test_dataset = train_test_split(dataset_normalized['data'], dataset_normalized['label'], test_size=0.10, random_state=0)
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`'data'` and `'label'` are not indices but keys of a dictionnary. This dictionary is accessible and calling `__getitem__` as follows : `dataset_normalized[idx]` with idx an integer.

Moreover, you cannot invoke your transformation directly on a dictionary. You should call it on `sample['data']` instead.

I advise you to carefully read this [example](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) of the PyTorch documentation which is very nice.

Comment: Now I get `TypeError: pic should be PIL Image or ndarray. Got <class 'torch.Tensor'>`

Comment: Actually `sample['data']`  is already a tensor. So `ToTensor()` is useless.